# Linear Programming - Motivation behind the Dual Simplex Method

Tags: linear-programming, operations-research, simplex-method

I am trying to understand the motivation behind the Dual Simplex Method. However, I have run into some roadblocks while understanding the rationale behind the Dual Simplex Method. This is my current understanding of the Simplex, the Primal and Dual problem:

> $1$. For a minimization problem, the Simplex Algorithm proceeds with first a basic feasible solution; then it replaces individual basis columns with an external column until $c_j - C_B B^{-1} A_j >0~\forall~j$ where $c_j$ is the $jth$ cost tuple ; $C_B$ is the cost corresponding to the feasible basis $B$ and $A_j$ is the $jth$ column external to $B$.
>
> $2$. If $x_0$ be the primal feasible solution and $y_0$ be the dual feasible solution and both satisfy the complementary slackness conditions, then $x_0$ is the primal optimal solution and $y_0$ is the dual optimal solution.
>
> $3$. If $c^T x_0 = b^T y_0$ where $B$ is the feasible basis, then $x_0$ is the primal optimal solution and $y_0$ forms the dual optimal solution.

Using this, my professor has tried to implement the Dual Simplex Algorithm by first accounting for a tuple of the RHS $:b_r < 0$ and then proceeding ahead.

**However, I do not quite understand the need to consider $b_r < 0$ nor the algorithm ahead. My confusion is: - The simplex method is applied to the dual formulation without explicitly finding the dual. How is that done?Could someone help me build the dual simplex algorithm from here?**

Comment: Do you understand the motivation behind the dual problem?

Comment: @Tab1e Yes, sometimes finding the optimal solution to the primal problem may be tedious. So instead we write the dual problem and then find it's optimal solution.

Comment: What about the formulation of the dual problem?

Comment: @Tab1e For a minimisation problem, the dual is obtained as a maximization problem  by rewriting the statement

Comment: Then the dual simplex method is simply the simplex method on the dual formulation, where is your confusion?

Comment: @Tab1e Do we need to explicitly find the dual to follow the dual simplex method? My confusion is : - The simplex method is applied on the dual formulation without explicitly finding the dual. How is that done?

Comment: The dual simplex method essentially writes out the matrix form of the dual dictionary during the computation. What you called rewriting the statement is a negative transpose of the prime dictionary, and that is done in the computation if you compare the two.

Comment: @Tab1e Thank you for the answer. If I may request, could you please write an answer explaining this? This is exactly what I wanted to understand on a deeper level. 

"The dual simplex method essentially writes out the matrix form of the dual dictionary during the computation. What you called rewriting the statement is a negative transpose of the prime dictionary, and that is done in the computation if you compare the two"

Comment: Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/8277/linear-programming-motivation-behind-the-dual-simplex-method

Answer (score 2):

After adding the slack variable, consider a standard-form linear programming problem:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\text{max} \quad &&c^Tx \\
&\text{subject to}\quad &&Ax = b \\
&&& x\geq 0
\end{align*}
$$
where the matrix $A$ is a partitioned-matrix form of $A = [B\ \ N]$. We can write
$$
x = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\
\vdots \\
x_n \\
w_1 = x_{n+1} \\
\vdots \\
w_m = x_{n+m}
\end{pmatrix} \quad \text{and}\quad z = \begin{pmatrix} z_1 \\
\vdots \\
z_n \\
y_1 = z_{n+1} \\
\vdots \\
y_m = z_{n+m}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $x_i$ are the primal variables, $w_i$ are the primal slacks, $z_i$ are the dual slacks, and $y_i$ are the dual variables. Let the subscript $N$ indicate the non-basis, and $B$ indicate the basis. Now the primal dictionary updates as:
$$
\begin{align*}
\zeta &= \bar{\zeta} - z_N^Tx_N \\
x_B &= \bar{x}_B - B^{-1}Nx_N
\end{align*}
$$
and the dual dictionary actually updates as
$$
\begin{align*}
-\zeta &= -\bar{\zeta} - \bar{x}_B^Tz_B \\
z_N &= \bar{z}_N + (B^{-1}N)^Tz_B
\end{align*}
$$
Notice that here $(B^{-1}N)^T$ is the negative transpose of $-B^{-1}N$.

Take a look at https://vanderbei.princeton.edu/542/lectures/lec6.pdf or Chapter 6 of the book [Linear Programming by Vanderbei](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4614-7630-6) for a detailed explanation of the negative transpose property.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will try reading from the book you mentioned.

Comment: Hi @Tab1e, this is unrelated to your answer, hence I would be deleting this comment soonest. Please could you help out with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4441875/585488